# Symfony2 Entities with extended Repository classes

Tags: symfony, overriding, entities

I hope I'm able to ask this question without annoying or giving someone a headache. I'm new to Symfony and trying to wrap my head around everything.

Here is what I want to do: In a bundle called CalendarBundle I have an `Event` Entity where the Repository class looks like this:

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $start
     * @param $end
     * @return array $events_array
     */
    public function queryByRange($start = "", $end = "")
    {
        // set start and end to this month if empty
        $start = ($start == "")
          ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')))
          : $start;
        $end = ($end == "")
          ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('t'), date('Y')))
          : $end;

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
          ->where('e.start > :start')
          ->andWhere('e.end < :end')
          ->setParameter('start', $start)
          ->setParameter('end', $end)
          ->orderBy('e.start', 'ASC');

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $start
     * @param string $end
     * @return array
     */
    public function findByRange($start = "", $end = "")
    {
        // set start and end to this month if empty
        $start = ($start == "")
          ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')))
          : $start;
        $end = ($end == "")
          ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('t'), date('Y')))
          : $end;

        $events = $this->queryByRange($start, $end)->getQuery()->getResult();

        $events_array = array();
        $prev_date = '';

        foreach($events as $event) {
            $start = $event->getStart()->format('Ymj');

            if ($prev_date == $start) {
                $events_array[$prev_date][] = $this->eventToArray($event);
            } else {
                $events_array[$start][] = $this->eventToArray($event);
            }

            $prev_date = $start;
        }

        return $events_array;
    }

    /**
     * @param Event $event
     * @return array
     */
    private function eventToArray(Event $event)
    {
        return array(
          'item' => array(
            'id' => $event->getId(),
            'name' => $event->getName(),
            'description' => $event->getDescription(),
            'type' => $event->getType(),
            'status' => $event->getStatus(),
            'start' => $event->getStart()->format('Ymd H:i:s'),
            'end' => $event->getEnd()->format('Ymd H:i:s'),
          ),
        );
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to extend this base Event Entity with several more specific events adding different event meta for each of these. I figure the `queryByRange` function needs to be rewritten to also get meta data, and so does the `eventToArray` function.

Later I'm displaying events using different twig templates using the Event item type to decide on templates used.

Now the thing that gives me a headache. Because I don't know what Events that may exist, I want to use this EventRepository class when getting all kinds of events in the Controller like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeCalendarBundle:Event'); 
$events = $repository->findByRange($start, $end);
```

and the correct extended class is used automagically to query and return events.

I found [this question where extending Bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010973/overriding-doctrine-entities) was the right way to do it. But I don't think this solves my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you wanted to achive:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\OwnBundle\Entity\Repository\EventRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"sport_event" = "SportEvent", "music_event" = "MusicEvent"})
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class SportEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="discipline", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $discipline;

    public function setDiscipline($discipline)
    {
        $this->discipline = $discipline;
    }

    public function getDiscipline()
    {
        return $this->discipline;
    }
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class MusicEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="band", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $band;

    public function setBand($band)
    {
        $this->band = $band;
    }

    public function getBand()
    {
        return $this->$band;
    }
}
```

And your event repository could be simply:

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
{

}
```

I didn't include the start and end fields on the entities, but assuming you have them, then you can do:

```
$repository->findBy(['start' => $start, 'end' => $end])
```

Assuming $start and $end are correct \DateTime objects, the result would be a list of entities with match the specified date range, but each individual object would be of appropriate class (eg. MusicEvent, SportEvent).

Read more here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: Awesome! I will check out a way to have the event meta in different tables, but if that is not possible, one table will do. Thank you!

Comment: Exciting possibilities! I did not know about this :) found an example of class table inheritance here that I will test later: https://gist.github.com/Problematic/983982